# Calculating the farthest point from a set of other points

Tags: c++, math

I am developing a simulation, where I have a two-dimensional field with a set height and length (say, 100m x 100m). Now I have some points in that field with x- and y-coordinates ( not many, around 6 or 7). Now I am to calculate (or simply approximate) the point, which is the farthest away from all those other points.

In my reseach for that topic I found the concept of convex hulls, which i think won't help me, and [spherical Voronoi diagrams](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17358/how-can-i-find-the-farthest-point-from-a-set-of-existing-points), which frankly wouldn't know how to implement.

Can anyone hint me to a possible, more simple, solution or propose a sample code? I am aiming to implement it in a C++ method with the output of x-and y-coordinates of a point.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried implementing so far? Why is a naive solution not good enough for you, considering the small scale of your problem? Are you having trouble with the algorithm, or with the implementation in C++?

Comment: Do you know how:  to calculate the distance between points?  to push_back the distances in to a vector?  to sort the vector?  Do you need to compute the quantity of 7 things taken 2 at a time (i.e. combinations? permutations?)  What do you need help with?

Comment: Are you looking for some point on the field or one of the 6 or 7 input points?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick responses. I am mainly looking for an idea on how to calculate the coordinates of a point, which has the maximum distance to the aforementioned 6 already set points(they have coordiantes i can read and use).
I haven't implemented anything, because i dont know what my calculations for the x and y coordinates are. The solution should be mathematically "correct", i need at least a suitable approximation.I need help with the algorithm. The implementation, i can take care of myself.

Comment: Do you want us to suggest good math books that will help you with coordinate plane problems?

Comment: @MPops That would indeed help me already :P i feel ashamed for not checking this kind of source earlier

Comment: Okay, I would suggest starting with modeling the data, like a `struct point` with two coordinates: x and y. Then, start implementing some basic functions for this data type. For example, a distance function that takes two `point` objects, and returns how far apart they are on the coordinate plane. Make some tests to ensure this function is correct, and continue building from there.

Comment: You need spherical Voronoi diagrams only when you are looking for a point on a sphere farthest away from other points on a sphere. In your case, a simple 2d [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) will suffice. To calculate that, wikipedia links, e.g., to [Fortune's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm)

Comment: Normal "outlier" analysis should help. If all things are equal, you can just approach it as a *center of mass* problem and take the furthest point from the center.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In the case where the points are all on the outer edges of the space, the centre of mass of the points is the centre of the space, which is also the furthest point from all the other points.

Comment: In that case you have the points lying on a perfect-circle. In the case of a rectangle, then you have 4 points eqi-distant from the center, lying on the boundaries of a triangle -- 3 points. Otherwise your will have a single outlier.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't think he's trying to find the point in the set that's furthest from the other points, I think he's trying to find the point in the 100x100 space that's furthest from the other points. That is, in the corners-of-the-rectangle case, he wants the centre of the 100x100 space to be output.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare every points to the centre of gravity of the x- and y-coordinates of your points you want compare.

To have the point which represents all the points you want compare you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, sumx = 0, sumy = 0 ;

       /* or use this
            int a,sum;
            sum = 0;
        */


    int arrayx[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int arrayy[] = {5, 5, 7, 9, 14};
    int length = 5;

    for (a=0; a<length; a++)
    {
        sumx+=arrayx[a];
        sumy+=arrayy[a];
    }

int gravx = sumx/length;
int gravy = sumy/length;

cout << "Grav of x = " << gravx << endl;
cout << "Grav of y = " << gravy << endl;

return 0;
}
```

you can try the code here :
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Comment: The case where all the points are distributed around the edges of the 100 x 100 space and the case where all the points are at the centre of the space have the same centre of gravity, but different farthest points; this can't possibly work.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blog.ivank.net/fortunes-algorithm-and-implementation.html) website contains a description of an algorithm for computing a Voronoi diagram for your points, as well as a C++ implementation in a zipfile. If my mathematical intuition is correct, the farthest point from any of your points in your 100x100 space should be a vertex in the voronoi diagram (if you include edges around the edges of your space). So if you compute the diagram and then test every vertex of the diagram you should find the farthest point.

Comment: Although now that I think about it you might have to be clearer what you mean by 'farthest point'. Point with the largest distance to the closest point to it? Point with the largest average distance to all other points? Point with the largest sum of distances to all other points? Those three metrics give different answers I think.

Answer (score -1):

My approach:

Prepare a matrix of distances, for the set of the 7 points you will have 49 distance values. Then write the sum of values for each row or you can compute the sums for each column. The reference point of the row(or column) that has the highest sum is the point that is approximately farthest to all other points in the data-set. This can be done fast only for limited number of points.

Babu V Bassa.